# Send data to restful service

Tags: jquery, json, rest, jsonp

Im trying to send data as json string to restful service. As it is a cross domain call im using jsonp to do this.

```
var arr={"isExceptionLogged":"0","allocInstructionId":"000001879HVWC1","allocInstructionIdtmp":"000001879HVWC}
               $.support.cors = true;
               $.ajax( {
                     headers: {
                         'Accept': 'application/json',
                     },
                     crossDomain: true,
                     url: "http://<url>",
                     type: "POST",
                     data: JSON.stringify( arr ),
                     dataType: "jsonp",

                     success: function ( result )
                     {
                         alert("successful");
                       },
                     error: function ( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError )
                     {
                         alert( "Error" );
                         alert( xhr.status );
                         alert( thrownError );
                     }
                 } );
```

But im getting the error 200 , jquery= 12345 was not called.

my service code is :

```
@Path("/update")
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void updatefunctions(bean abc){

    abc.toString();
}
```

Comment: Post this query in their discussion forum and they will help you to solve..

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the string for the value of 'allocInstructionIdtmp' in the array var. It should be:

```
var arr={"isExceptionLogged":"0","allocInstructionId":"000001879HVWC1","allocInstructionIdtmp":"000001879HVWC**"**}**;**
```

Comment: im closing it in the code. Its a huge string so I trimmed it to post it here